# What's my URL path for my Ajax request to my JSP controller?

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, post, intellij-idea

I am trying to learn JSP, and to do so I am building a simple web application that allows the user to click on a DIV with a particular colour - upon doing so, the user will be alerted of the Hex value for this colour.

I am having troubles with linking up my Ajax request to my controller - it does sound easy but you'll have to forgive me because I am new to JSP.

This is my JQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function ()
{

    $(".wbbButton").click(function()
    {
         var item = $(this).attr('id');
        alert("Starting...");

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            // url: "AjaxController",
            data: {param: item},
            success: function()
            {
               alert("Ending...");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This is my JSP Controller:

```
package controller;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

@WebServlet(name = "AjaxController")
public class AjaxController extends HttpServlet
{
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        String color = request.getParameter("param");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.print("You selected: " + color);
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
    }
}
```

My project structure is as follows:

app_Test

```
.idea


out


src


    controller


        AjaxController


web


    css


    js


    listener


        colourListener.js 


    WEB-INF


    index.jsp
```

The alerts are just to show that my JQuery is working. If I comment out the url, the last alert executes so I'm presuming that my problem is my url and not my controller.

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks.

PS - My IDE is IntelliJ IDEA for JSP.

Comment: did you map your servlet in you web.xml?

Comment: No. I have followed various tutorials online and they've said something along the lines of because we're using Java EE Web Application 3.0+ we don't need to map it...

Comment: In you @WebServlet annotation, you can add an attribute for urlPatterns={"/pathToServlet"} So   your annotation would look like @WebServlet(name="AjaxController", urlPatterns={"/thePathYouWantToThisServlet"})

Comment: http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/webservlet-annotation-examples

Comment: Will my ajax use the same path as {"/thePathYouWantToThisServlet"}?

Comment: you can make /thePathYouWantToThisServlet can be anything you want.  As far as jQuery I believe you need the full path.  If you running on your local machine "http://localhost:8080/applicationName/thePathYouWantToThisServlet"